# Count down timers recyclerview - android

Tags: android, synchronization, android-recyclerview, runnable, countdowntimer

I've been working on an app for quite some time now. This app is supposed to take family names and measure a visit time, which is constant(30 minutes). I have a Family object which holds info such as name, number of members and the end of the visit, represented as a future milliseconds value.

The way I've implemented the timers part is simply create a class called CountDownManager which is responsible for updating and calculating the remaining time for all the families' view holders that are listed.

The problem is that whenever I remove a family(list item) from the recycler view, I'm getting a NullPointerException error from my CountDownManager.

Basically I think that the CountDownManager is trying to access a family that is no longer available in the dataset. I tried to resolve this by simply synchronizing the part where I remove a family but it still keeps crashing with the same error.

Here is the code for my FamiliesAdapter:

```
package bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.Constants;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters.holders.FamilyViewHolder;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters.holders.GenericViewHolder;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters.holders.TimeUpViewHolder;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.models.Family;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.R;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.Utils;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.interfaces.HolderListener;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.managers.CountDownManager;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.interfaces.EventListener;

public class FamiliesAdapter extends GenericAdapter implements Filterable, EventListener, HolderListener {

    // last position holds the last position of the element that was added, for animation purposes
    private static int lastPosition = -1;

    private int[] viewTypes;

    private ItemTouchHelper touchHelper;

    private CountDownManager countDownManager;

    public FamiliesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Family> families, ItemTouchHelper touchHelper) {
        super(context, families);
        this.touchHelper = touchHelper;

        viewTypes = Constants.Tags.VIEW_TYPES;

        countDownManager = new CountDownManager(Constants.Values.TIME_INTERVAL, this);
        countDownManager.start();
    }


    @Override
    public GenericViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Inflating the view from a given layout resource file
        Log.d("A function has called", "onCreateViewHolder() was invoked");
        View v;
        switch (viewType) {
            case Constants.Tags.FAMILY_VIEW:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.family_list_item, parent, false);
                FamilyViewHolder fvh = new FamilyViewHolder(context, v);
                return fvh;
            case Constants.Tags.TIME_UP_VIEW:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.timeup_list_item, parent, false);
                TimeUpViewHolder tvh = new TimeUpViewHolder(context, v, this);
                return tvh;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GenericViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Binds the Family object to the holder view
        Family family = families.get(position);
        holder.bindData(family);

        Log.d("A function has called", "onBindViewHolder() was invoked, FAMILY NAME: " + family.name);

        if(holder instanceof FamilyViewHolder){
            countDownManager.addHolder((FamilyViewHolder) holder);
        }

        // Sets animation on the given view, in case it wasn't displayed before
        Utils.setSlideAnimation(context, holder.getView(), position, lastPosition, false);
    }
    // If the time of family has ended, return TIME_UP_VIEW
    // else, return FAMILY_VIEW
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(families.get(position).whenInMillis <= System.currentTimeMillis())
            return viewTypes[1];
        return viewTypes[0];
    }

    /* Changes the UI of a holder to a time's up view with a flickering ImageButton and a TextView*/

    @Override
    public void onFinish(FamilyViewHolder holder) {
        // Switches between the clock icon to the alarm icon
        holder.reset();
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLessThanMinute(FamilyViewHolder holder) {
        Drawable stroke = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.family_item_red_stroke);
        holder.frame.setBackground(stroke);

        Utils.setFadeAnimation(holder.frame);
        holder.isStrokeChanged = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveTimeUpViewHolder(int pos, GenericViewHolder holder) {
        touchHelper.startSwipe(holder);
        removeData(pos, holder);
    }

    public void removeData(int pos, GenericViewHolder holder) {
        // Sets the last position to the given deleted position for animation purposes
        lastPosition = pos;

        // Removes the family object from the data set
        String name = Utils.getLastName(families.get(pos).name);

        families.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, getItemCount());

        if(holder instanceof FamilyViewHolder)
            // Cancels the the timer and removes it from the entry set
            countDownManager.removeHolder((FamilyViewHolder) holder);

        holder.reset();
        Toast.makeText(context, "משפחת "+name+" נמחקה מהרשימה", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /* Cancels the timers and clears the entry set */
    public void cancelTimers() {
        countDownManager.reset();
        countDownManager.clear();
        countDownManager.stop();
    }

    /* Clears the adapter's data and resets the last position to -1 */
    @Override
    public void clearData() {
        super.clearData();
        cancelTimers();
        lastPosition = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(GenericViewHolder holder) {
        holder.reset();
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }
}
```

Here is the CountDownManager:

```
package bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.managers;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;

import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.Constants;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.adapters.holders.FamilyViewHolder;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.interfaces.EventListener;
import bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.Utils;

/**
 * Created by David on 07/07/2016.
 * @author David
 * Inspired by MiguelLavigne
 *
 * A custom CountDownTimer class, which takes care of all the running timers
 */
public class CountDownManager {

    private final long interval;
    private long base;

    // Holds references for all the visible text views
    private ArrayList<FamilyViewHolder> holders;

    private EventListener listener;

    public CountDownManager(long interval, EventListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.interval = interval;
        holders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void start() {
        base = System.currentTimeMillis();
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG));
    }

    public void stop() {
        handler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    public void reset() {
        synchronized (this) {
            base = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    public void addHolder(FamilyViewHolder holder) {
        synchronized (holders) {
            if(holder.isHolderAdded == false) {
                holders.add(holder);
                holder.isHolderAdded = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeHolder(FamilyViewHolder holder) {
        synchronized (holders) {
            holders.remove(holder);
        }
    }

    synchronized void onTick(long elapsedTime) {
       try {
           if(!holders.isEmpty()) {
               long timeLeft, lengthOfVisit;
               for (FamilyViewHolder holder : holders) {
                   lengthOfVisit = holder.family.whenInMillis - base;
                   timeLeft =  lengthOfVisit - elapsedTime;
                   if(timeLeft > 0) {
                       Log.d("Time left:", "" + timeLeft);
                       if(timeLeft <= Constants.Values.ALERT_TIME && !holder.isStrokeChanged) {
                           listener.onLessThanMinute(holder);
                       }
                       holder.family.timeLeft = timeLeft;
                       holder.timeLeft.setText(Utils.updateFormatTime(timeLeft));
                   } else {
                       listener.onFinish(holder);
                       removeHolder(holder);
                   }
               }
           }
       } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            Log.d("Concurrent Error", "App will shut down now");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public void clear() {
        holders.clear();
    }

    private static final int MSG = 1;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            synchronized (CountDownManager.this) {
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
                onTick(elapsedTime);
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), interval);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And in my activity, here is the part where I delete items, using swipe movement by ItemTouchHelper:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback callback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                final int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FamilyListActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmation_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.proceed_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                synchronized (families) {
                                    Family family = families.get(pos);
                                    GenericViewHolder holder = null;
                                    try {
                                        holder = (GenericViewHolder) viewHolder;
                                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    String whereClause = FamiliesTablesContract.DATE_COLUMN + "=?";
                                    String args[] = new String[] {"" + family.date};
                                    Cursor cursor = dataManager.query(FamiliesTablesContract.TABLE_NAME, whereClause, args);
                                    int entryId = 0;

                                    try {
                                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                                        entryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FamiliesTablesContract._ID));
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    reminderManager.cancelReminder(entryId);
                                    String name = family.name;

                                    adapter.removeData(pos, holder);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
07-14 19:34:03.742 5597-5597/bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim, PID: 5597
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.models.Family.whenInMillis' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.managers.CountDownManager.onTick(CountDownManager.java:73)
                                                                                 at bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.managers.CountDownManager$1.handleMessage(CountDownManager.java:105)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Where using `CountDownManager ` class?

Comment: In my adapter. Basically whenever a new family view holder is created, I add it to the CountDownManager object in onBindViewHolder. The CountDownManager holds a list of all the view holders that are still running and need to updated

Comment: As in log `holder.family` is null so check Adapter code

Comment: Ok so I managed to solve this by simply removing the onViewRecycled method in my adapter which I overrided. Thank you!